# pari gp return function store in variable

Tags: pari, pari-gp

I'm new to pari gp, and just trying out, playing with it.
i have an inverse function that goes like this.

```
inverse (a,n) = 
{
  negative = false;

  if (a < 0, negative = true);
  if (a < 0, a= a*-1);

  i = n;
  v = 0;
  d = 1;

  while (a>0,t=i/a; x =a;
        a = i % x;
        i = x;
        x = d;
        d = v - t*x;
        v = x);
    v %= n;

  if (v < 0, v = (v+n)%n);


  if (negative == true, return (-v));

  return (v);
};
```

so i have sort of a main function, which consist of something like this.

```
while (i<n,i++;
    while(j<n,j++;
      // some other codes
      temp1 = inverse(temp,modulus)));
```

I got an error that says incorrect type in &*[*] 0Ccompo1ptr [not a vector] (t_INT)
i am quite sure that the rest of the code is work fine, since the error only occurred when i place

```
temp1 = inverse (temp,modulus)
```

in.

Comment: Thanks for updating the Question to make a connection between the line where the error is reported and the function `inverse` with which your discussion begins.  It still does not seem to be [a minimal, complete and verifiable illustration](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Is it necessary to (for purpose of illustration) put the call to `inverse` in a doubly nested loop?  We do not see how the arguments `temp,modulus` are being assigned values in this snippet.  What happens if `inverse` is called once, with explicit arguments?  Etc.

Comment: @hardmath. Thanks for the reply. inverse function will print out the correct answer. If i place it in the loop. it doesnt work and i'll get that error.

Comment: Show me the code!  Strategy: one things works, the other doesn't.  Narrow down the difference.  To do it you have to be able to see both, and change things until the error is isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem here is that you are not scoping variables in the function. In particular you are using `i` both inside the function and out. None of this is explained well in the PARI user manual. To make a variable local you need to do something like `my(i=n);` Some variables are automatically scoped such as arguments to functions and `sum(i=1,10,i); vector(10,i,i^2); for(i=1,10,...)` etc, but not simple assignments like `i=n`. Also note PARI does not have boolean constants `true` and `false`. Your code works in this case because you are doing `negative==true` which is just comparing polynomials with the indeterminants of `true` of and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your function with one with properly-scoped variables should solve the problem. Try this:

```
inverse (a,n) = 
{
  if (a < 0, return(-inverse(-a, n)));
  my(i = n, v = 0, d = 1);
  while (a > 0,
    my(x = a, t);
    [t, a] = divrem(i,a);
    i = x;
    [d, v] = [v - t*x, d];
  );
  v % n;
}
```